# How to make sure that a external drive is mounted before copying files to it through a scheduled backup

Tags: mount, hard-drive, backup, cron

I was having a lot of trouble with backup software so I decided to create my own backup code and scheduled it via crontab. Everything was going smoothly until a couple of weeks ago. My computer rebooted and the external hard drive where I am doing my backup got disconnected. However, the scheduled backup continued and saved all the info in my main SDD that only has ~250 GB. Therefore, it filled the SDD completely and the computer crashed because it didn't have any memory left.

So my question is: Is there a way that I can tell the computer to make sure the external hard drive is connected before copying/synchronizing the information I want to avoid my SDD to be filled in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the exit status of the `mountpoint` command to determine whether a given path is an active mountpoint or just a regular directory:

```
$ mountpoint /home ; echo $?
/home is a mountpoint
0

$ mountpoint /var ; echo $?
/var is not a mountpoint
1
```

So for example you could do something like

```
if ! mountpoint -q /path/to/backupmount; then
  # attempt to mount the backup drive
  # exit on error
fi

# continue with backup
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much. I haven't tried it yet but this opens the possibility of using an if condition to make or not the backup. I will update later if it worked!

Comment: @ZaidaMartínez exactly - see edit for an example usage

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the **mount** command or the **findmnt** command to verify this.

I found this in the **mount** manual

Listing the mounts
       The following command lists all mounted filesystems (of type type):
              mount [-l] [-t type]
       The option -l adds labels to this listing.  See below.

To check a pendrive for example I would use: **mount -l | grep sdb**
I used sdb, but it will depend on what type of device it is.

If you have any questions about the device, then visit link:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Device_file